# canvas-ui error on flipper.contract upload during substrate ink-workshop

Tags: ink, smart-contract

When uploading the wasm binary, as a compiled smart contract on the 'ink-workshop' - the `canvas-ui` that I am running just errors.

Canvas-ui error:

```
Uncaught error. Something went wrong with the query and rendering of this component. 
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'args')
```

[image]

Step: 'Drag the flipper.contract file that contains the bundled wasm blob....'

The Github issues section associated is read-only, hence why I am posting here. Anyone know what might be the problem here?

Comment: @NukeManDan as requested.

Comment: Thanks for cross posting!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There was an update to the metadata format of a contract (part of the `.contract` file). The Canvas UI referenced in the tutorial wasn't updated to handle this. Reason for that is that it is soon to be replaced by [Contracts UI](https://contracts-ui.substrate.io/).

In the meantime you should use the `Developer -> Contracts` tab of [Polkadot.js Apps](https://polkadot.js.org/apps) to interact with your contracts. You can use the sidebar on the top left to connect to a local node [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIxAz.jpg).

[image: Screenshot of Polkadot.js Apps]

Comment: I'm using Polkadot.js Apps for interacting with Rococo Canvas chain for now to avoid above issue. However, App UI has no reaction when clicking Read button for calling Read methods (for example, totalSupply() of my PSP22Token contract). Execute methods works. Does anyone face with the same situation?